# Tangible TemplateFileManager Error

Tags: visual-studio-2017, t4, envdte, tangible-t4-editor

I was trying to use the TemplateFileManager TT Include file (referenced from [this article](https://t4-editor.tangible-engineering.com/blog/how-to-generate-multiple-output-files-from-a-single-t4-template.html), and available in Tangible's template gallery) so that I could output multiple files from 1 T4 template, but I keep getting an error inside the default code.  For some reason, this method returns null, and I cannot debug it easily enough to know why.

```
public static string GetProjectItemFullPath(EnvDTE.ProjectItem item)
{
    return item.Properties.Item("FullPath").Value.ToString();
}
```

Anybody know why?  I did download the latest version (2.1) from their template download tool.  My usage was very straightforward; I was trying to write out 2 CSV files.  I have this declared:

```
<#@ output extension=".csv" #>
<#@ include file="TemplateFileManager.ttinclude" #>
```

At the top I create the TemplateManager:

```
var manager = TemplateFileManager.Create(this);
```

and when I want to split, I have this:

```
manager.StartNewFile("Documentation.Features.csv");
```

And at the end:

```
manager.Process();
```

I can debug through to know that the issue is with CleanupTemplatePlaceholders routine:

```
var dirtyHelperTemplates = VSHelper.GetAllSolutionItems(this.dte)
        .Where(p => delta.Contains(VSHelper.GetProjectItemFullPath(p)));
```

In this collection is an instance where something is null... (Object reference error).

Comment: Attach another instance to debug it. Or simply rewrite it to throw when a null is first detected so you can figure out what's null (Value, I'd bet). Sounds like a bug on their part, no matter what. They'll need more details on *how* you are using it in order to repro.

Comment: Every time I try to use the immediate window, it is locking up (or taking a REALLY REALLY long time to come back with anything), so I gave up on that effort.  V2.1 has been around for a really long time, which is why I thought someone would have experienced this...  But I couldn't find any resolutions.  I updated my example above.  I wonder if it may because I'm outputting CSV?